# "Не" с прилагательными 5

Tags: частица-не, слитно-раздельно

В СССР не было такого образования, подбора и расстановки руководящих кадров, компенсирующих преодоление не кардинальных дефектов системы и продлевающих ей жизнь.

"Некардинальных" в данном случае слитно?

Answer (score 1):

Наверно, слитно... Хотя мне очень не нравится это присобачивание НЕ чуть ли не к любым словам. Лучше бы поискать синоним, но если нет – то придется слитно.

Comment: Спасибо. Мне тоже кажется, что раздельно нельзя, здесь же нет противопоставления, наоборот утверждается одним словом отрицательный признак.